# Python multiprocessing and reading huge files is slow

Tags: python, file, multiprocessing, hard-drive

I am using the multiprocessing package for python to launch different processes that do some work. This work is performed after reading huge files. Those files must be loaded by each process, so, there are many processes trying to get different huge files from the same hard drive at the same time, which saturates the reading buffer. It gives me a very slow performance. My question is: Is there any way to tell Python does not try to open a file until the reading buffer is below a certain value? Or which is the strategy to follow when you want to perform a multiprocessing work by accessing huge files from the same hard drive?
Thanks,
Alejandro

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way to divide large files in Python for multiprocessing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823300/whats-the-best-way-to-divide-large-files-in-python-for-multiprocessing)

Comment: You should limit the number of processes, so not to thrash the hard drive. For mechanical hard drives, often the fastest is to just have one process!

Comment: multiprocessing is better when you can improve performance by splitting the work among several CPUs, but in general will perform badly if the tasks are I/O bound and you have limited I/O capacity.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I Agree with the three, but it is not the same that divide large files in Python for multiprocessing. Each process need all the data in each file, so, is not possible to divide it. The problem is a bottleneck when multiple processes ask for files at the same time. One can increase the computation power by forcing some processes to stop until the reading buffer drops below a certain value. It should avoid such a bottleneck and allows that every process works when the reading buffer is small. May be such thing does not exist and one have to work with one file per time.

Comment: how many MB/GB are the files?

Comment: I'm just spitballing here, but one thing to do is just read them all in once and store the contents of each in redis. Then, spawn as many processes as you like and just pull them out of redis. This of course assumes that you can store them all in memory...

Comment: Also, are you sure that you are saturating the read buffer or moving into swap space due to memory limitations?

Comment: The files are 1 Gb. I have no problems with the ram. I know that one can load the data first and then spawn the work among the processors. Also, I have checked that I am not writting on the swap. Let's put the question in other way: Is there a function to check out the status of the reading buffer of the hard drive? Thanks to all for your comments.