# Sharing state between forked worker processes in a high-performance environment

Tags: python, concurrency, machine-learning, nlp

This is a follow up to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20955683/python-multiprocessing-sharing-a-complex-object/). As suggested by Tim Peters, using a `Manager` may not necessarily be the best approach. Unfortunately I've got too much scaffolding code to post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Instead, I'll try to provide a detailed explanation of my problem. Please feel free to browse the entire codebase on [Github](https://github.com/mbatchkarov/thesisgenerator), but it's a bit of a mess right now.

### Background

I am doing research in Natural Language Processing and I'd like to do (something like) dictionary-based smoothing for document classification. The idea to train a classifier to associate words and phrases with a correct answer. For example, documents containing the word `socialist` are likely to be about politics, and those containing the phrase `lava temperature` are likely about geology. The system is trained by looking at a **small number** of pre-labelled examples. Because language is so varied, a classifier will never "know about" all possible phrases that it might encounter in production.

This is where the dictionary comes in. Suppose we had [a cheap and easy way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173225/how-to-calculate-cosine-similarity-given-2-sentence-strings-python/15173821#15173821) of getting synonyms for almost any phrase out there (I'll cite myself because it's poor taste). When the poor classifier is faced with a phrase it doesn't know about, we could look it up in said dictionary and tell the classifier "Look, you do not know about `communism`, but it's kinda like `socialist`, and you know about that!". If the dictionary is reasonable, the classifier will generally perform better.

### Pseudo code

```
data = Load training and testing documents (300MB on disk)
dictionary = Load dictionary (200MB - 2GB on disk) and place into a `dict` for fast look-ups
Repeat 25 times:
    do_work(data, dictionary)

def do_work(data, dictionary)
    X = Select a random sample of data
    Train a classifier on X
    Y = Select a random sample of data
    Using dictionary, classify all documents in Y
    Write results to disk
```

### The problem

The loop above is a perfect candidate for parallelisation. I have been using a Python 2.7  `multiprocessing.Pool` (through `joblib.Parallel`, because it’s easy and provides very useful traceback if things go south). All worker processes need read-only access to the dictionary and the document collection. There is no need for the workers to communicate with one another or with the parent process- all they do is spawn, do some magic, write a file and die.

The dictionary needs to support fast random access. I do not know what documents the sample `Y` will contain, so I cannot easily prune the dictionary and pass just the part of it that is needed to each worker. The dictionary will be queried very often- typical hit counts per run are in the millions.
Currently my code is memory-bound as (I believe) copies of the document collection and dictionary are being made for each worker process. When parsed `data` and `dictionary` typically use up several GB of RAM. I’ve tried using `multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager` to avoid copying the large objects, but that slowed the workers down.

### The question

What other alternatives are there to speed things up? Things I have thought about include:

- MongoDB/CouchDB/memcached should handle concurrent access well, but I’m worried about throughput. zeromq was also suggested in a comment to my previous question, haven't had a chance to look into it.
- in-memory `sqlite` databases and database connections cannot be shared across processes, so each worker will need its own connection to an on-disk database. This means a lot of I/O at first and high memory usage as each worker's cache grows.
- memory mapping
- using threads instead of processes

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659865/python-multiprocessing-sharing-a-large-read-only-object-between-processes) also suggested that many real-world problems that look like they need read-only access to a `dict` may trigger `fork()`'s copy-on-write, so it may be impossible to completely avoid making copies of large objects.

Comment: The very latest joblib, 0.8, has a threading backend. **If** your code uses enough NumPy (or other C code that releases the GIL), that might be as fast as multiprocessing but with shared memory.

Comment: Consider using the [`shelve`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html#module-shelve) module. Its cached memory usage can be kept under control by periodically calling `Shelf.sync()` which should be fast if you're not modifying its content.

Comment: Try the simplest thing first: what happens if you "simply" create `data` and `dictionary` at module level, and let worker processes inherit copies via `fork()`? The SO post you linked to warning about reference counts is quite relevant here, but there's absolutely no way to guess how _much_ that matters for _your_ data and access patterns without trying it. The author of that post was, generally speaking. too pessimistic.

Comment: This is an interesting idea---do you have a paper yet to cite? and how does it compare to LDA/dimensionality reduction for solving the oov problem?

Answer (score 2):

The scenario you describe, you are likely to have large performance issues due to the GIL when using multi-threading.  Probably to avoid that you chose to use multi processing instead.  That, on the other hand, uses processes, so data structures might get copied for each subprocess.

I hate to say it, but using a non-Python solution (e. g. in C++) might speed up things because there you do not have the GIL problem.  Then you can use multi-threading, do not have to copy things etc.  Reading from a large dictionary from several threads is not really an issue, so you won't have to synchronize anything (what the GIL always would do for you without a real need).