# Python interprocess communictation, huge data

Tags: python, image-processing, ipc

What is the best way to exchange huge amount of data between processes in python. I am working on the image processing algorithms and I would like to send image frames between processes.

Comment: I had a similar question a while back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20971191/sharing-state-between-forked-worker-processes-in-a-high-performance-environment. Unfortunately I didn't find a satisfactory solution. I ended up running all code in a single process. That wasn't an issue because I was able to run multiple experiments, with different parameter settings, at the same time.

Comment: Use `shm_open` maybe? It would seem more efficient to use shared memory rather than moving vast quantities of data around needlessly as messages.

Answer (score 1):

For interprocess communication between Python processes you should use the asynchronous message queuing communication protocol.

Python has great support for a variety of systems implementing this as [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/bindings:python) and [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html).

Or you can check out the [listener and client](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-listeners-clients) objects of the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) library.