# Python: How to share an Unpickable Object

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am doing some multiprocessing and I need to share an instance between two processes. I have been trying to use the multiprocessing module to try and accomplish this but there isn't much hope to share anything that can't be pickled it seems; so far I have tried to use a manager and create a proxy object to handle my object by following [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20955683/python-multiprocessing-sharing-a-complex-object) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671666/sharing-a-complex-object-between-python-processes). I understand that sharing mutable object instances isn't exactly python's forte, but what is the easiest way to do this?

To layout my situation more clearly, I am working on UNIX systems exclusively so it uses forks and copy-on-write memory management to my understanding. This object that I need to share is read-only on the main process but read and write on the subprocess. The easiest way I can think of doing this is to just share a reference to the object instance in memory to the subprocess and communicate between processes not to write when the object is being used by the main process.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiprocessing Share Unserializable Objects Between Processes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21968278/multiprocessing-share-unserializable-objects-between-processes)

Comment: What problems are you facing using a manager?

Comment: @User I can't use the register method for my classes because they cannot be serialised.

Comment: @User I think I just solved it. I was using a synch manager to register my classes instead of a base manager. I will a few more tests and if the issue is solved I will close the thread.

Comment: @User So it turns out that was the problem. So should I keep this thread with my solution, because I don't think I will be the only person that will try to register a class using a synch manager thinking that it will work because the synch manager is a subclass of base manager.

Comment: You should answer your own question and accept it as answer. That helps other people find the solution faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem myself, but for anyone who comes to this thread with the same problem:

I made the mistake of instantiating a [SyncManager()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager) object then calling the [BaseManager.register()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager.register) method assuming this would work since SyncManager is just a subclass of [BaseManager()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager). I didn't look into exactly why this is the case, but I do know the fix, and that is to just instantiate a [BaseManager()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager) and register your Python object with that instead.