# multiprocessing.value clear syntax?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to use multiprocessing.Value to use a variable in multiple processes, but the syntax is not clear on Python's documentation. Can anyone tell me what should I use as type (my variable is a letter), and where to put my variable's name ?

EDIT

I tried using the Manager to share my letter between processes. But the only thing I have now is `Value('ctypes.c_char_p', '`(The key you hit here)`')` printed in the Python Shell and still no sound.
The console also seems a bit slower than usual when using the manager. There's an almost one second delay between the time I hit the key and when the `Value` appears on screen.

My code now looks like this :

```
#Import 
from tkinter import * 
import wave 
import winsound 
import multiprocessing 

#Functions 

def key(event):

     temp = event.char
     manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
     manager.Value(ctypes.c_char_p, temp)
     hitkey = manager.Value(ctypes.c_char_p, temp)
     instance = multiprocessing.Process(target=player, args=(hitkey,)) 
     instance.start()



def player(hitkey):
     print(hitkey + "1")
     winsound.PlaySound(hitkey + '.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME|winsound.SND_NOWAIT|winsound.SND_ASYNC) 


if __name__ == "__main__":



     #Initialisation 
     fenetre = Tk() 
     frame = Frame(fenetre, width=200, height=100)
     #TK

     frame.focus_set()
     frame.bind("<Key>", key)
     frame.pack()
     fenetre.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'm confused by the section of your code you've labeled `initialization`. A `global` statement at the top level of a module doesn't do anything. It's completely meaningless. What do you intend for `event` and `hitkey` to be there?

Comment: This is an old statement I forgot to remove. I don't think it will change anything.

Comment: Do you really need multiprocessing here? You certainly don't need a `Manager` or a `value` just to pass an argument to a new process (just let `multiprocessing` pass the string using `pickle`). Does your `player` function work if you simply call it from regular code, rather than in a separate process? I don't know `winsound` at all, so I can't help too much in debugging it.

Comment: @Blckknght I need to play multiple sounds at once, and Python's GIL prevents it. That's why I need multiprocessing.

Comment: Does the `player` function work if you test in a single process with the same arguments?

Comment: @Blckknght Yes, but the sounds just stop each other when playing.

Answer (score 17):

There is no special syntax for [`multiprocessing.Value`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value), it's just a class like any other. The *signature* of the `Value` constructor is *perfectly well described*:

> `multiprocessing.Value(typecode_or_type, *args[, lock])`
>
> Return a `ctypes` object allocated from shared memory. By default the return value is actually a synchronized wrapper for the object.
>
> `typecode_or_type` determines the type of the returned object: it is either a `ctypes` type or a one character typecode of the kind used
>   by the `array` module. `*args` is passed on to the constructor for the
>   type.
>
> If `lock` is `True` (the default) then a new lock object is created to synchronize access to the value. If lock is a `Lock` or
>   `RLock` object then that will be used to synchronize access to the
>   value. If `lock` is `False` then access to the returned object will
>   not be automatically protected by a lock, so it will not necessarily
>   be “process-safe”.

You even have some examples of its use [afterwards](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.sharedctypes.synchronized). In particolar the `typecode_or_type` can be one of the typecodes that are listed in the documentation for the [`array`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) module(e.g. `'i'` for signed integer, `'f'` for float etc.) or a `ctypes` type, like `ctypes.c_int` etc.

If you want to have a `Value` containing a single letter you can do:

```
>>> import multiprocessing as mp
>>> letter = mp.Value('c', 'A')
>>> letter
<Synchronized wrapper for c_char('A')>
>>> letter.value
'A'
```

**Update**

The problem with your code is that the typecode `'c'` means character **not** string.
If you want to hold a string you can use the type `ctypes.c_char_p`:

```
>>> import multiprocessing as mp
>>> import ctypes
>>> v = mp.Value('c', "Hello, World!")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/__init__.py", line 253, in Value
    return Value(typecode_or_type, *args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/sharedctypes.py", line 99, in Value
    obj = RawValue(typecode_or_type, *args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/sharedctypes.py", line 73, in RawValue
    obj.__init__(*args)
TypeError: one character string expected
>>> v = mp.Value(ctypes.c_char_p, "Hello, World!")
>>> v
<Synchronized wrapper for c_char_p(166841564)>
>>> v.value
'Hello, World!'
```

**For Python 3**, use `c_wchar_p` instead of `c_char_p`

Comment: Tried it, but then I've got an error in my multiprocessing line of code : `Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1399, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "G:\Projet final\Test audio\test4-2.py", line 16, in key
    hitkey = multiprocessing.Value('c', temp, False)`

Comment: `File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\multiprocessing\__init__.py", line 252, in Value
    return Value(typecode_or_type, *args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\multiprocessing\sharedctypes.py", line 96, in Value
    obj = RawValue(typecode_or_type, *args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\multiprocessing\sharedctypes.py", line 73, in RawValue
    obj.__init__(*args)
TypeError: __init__ expected at most 1 arguments, got 2`

Comment: @FalafHellFalafHell You are doing something wrong. *Show us the code!*

Comment: Here's the multiprocessing function : 
`def key(event): 
    temp = event.char 

     hitkey = multiprocessing.Value('c', temp, False)
     instance = multiprocessing.Process(target=player, args=(hitkey.Value,))
     instance.start()`

Comment: @FalafHellFalafHell Please edit your question and add code there. Also, instead of posting a small piece of the code that we are not able to run it's much more helpful if you can provide us with an entire program that reproduces the behaviour and that we are able to run on our computers.

Comment: @FalafHellFalafHell Can you edit your question and write the full traceback you are now getting? Anyway my guess is that you are trying to use `Value` to store some complex object, in which case you really should use the `Manager` class(see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671666/sharing-a-complex-object-between-python-processes) related question).

Comment: Edited, I'm afraid proxy bojects will be a little bit too complicated, will try it though.

Comment: @FalafHellFalafHell The argument for the type of `Value` is not the string `'ctypes.c_char_p'`. Is the *object* `c_char_p` from the module `ctypes`. Read carefully the last example in my answer.

Comment: I have found `v = mp.Value(ctypes.c_char_p, "Hello, World!")` to be problematic, leading to segmentation violation, because, I surmise, the item in shared memory is a pointer to a string, not the string itself.

Answer (score 2):

I think the original issue you were having (causing the `TypeError`) was because the `lock` argument to the `multiprocessing.Value` constructor is a keyword-only argument. You need to call `multiprocessing.Value("c", temp, lock=False)` in order for it to do what you were wanting to do.

However, I don't think you need to use a `Value` object at all. You're passing the keycode as an argument to your other process, and the `Value` isn't being used at all. I'd get rid of it completely:

```
def key(event): 
   instance = multiprocessing.Process(target=player, args=(event.char,)) 
   instance.start()
```

Comment: I tried `hitkey = multiprocessing.Value('c', temp, lock=False)`, I have a `TypeError: one character string expected` error. I also tried without the `Value` object, and again, no sound playing.

Comment: As I already pointed out in my answer the problem is that `'c'` expects a *single* character, while Falaf is passing in a string. Using a `ctypes.c_char_p` works.

Comment: Right, I forgot. Fixed it, but there's still this `TypeError: this type has no size`.

Comment: @FalafHellFalafHell: Have you tried the version without the `Value`? It should work regardless of what `event.char` is. It will work for any string. Of course, if the string is not what you expect, the other process may not find the `wav` file you're wanting it to play. You might want to print out `event.char` for debugging, to make sure it is what you expect.

Comment: @Blckknght Yes, I tried with `instance = multiprocessing.Process(target=player, args=(event.char,))` and `print(event.char)`,but the only thing I get is the letter printed, no sound.

Comment: @FalafHellFalafHell It looks like the `TypeError: one character string expected` was due to passing in a Unicode string (which is the default string type in Python 3). It works if you pass a `bytes` instance with a single character, and really it seems like a bug that it fails for ASCII characters in a unicode string (a bug in the error text at least). But I really don't understand why a `Value` or `Manager` is required here, since the value isn't going to be updated while the other process is running. Just pass the value directly, as I have in my example should work just as well.

Comment: @Blckknght I know, it should work, but it just doesn't. I tried with your exemple several times, and nothing happens.