# Creating a Multiprocessing Ordered Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I would like to create an `OrderedDict` instance that can be shared across processes.

### What I've tried

#### Intro

I've implemented a normal `dict` version, a multi-process `dict` version, as shown below.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

class BasicPen(object):
    """single process version"""

    def __init__(self, words):
        self.dogs = {"Molson": [], "Taco": [], "Lucky": []}
        self.punc = "!"
        for dog_name in self.dogs.keys():
            self.bark(dog_name, words)

    def bark(self, dog, words):
        for word in words:
            self.dogs[dog].append(word + self.punc)

class MultiPen(object):
    """multiprocess dict"""

    def __init__(self, words):
        self.man = mp.Manager()
        self.dogs = self.man.dict()
        self.dogs["Molson"] = self.man.list()
        self.dogs["Taco"] = self.man.list()
        self.dogs["Lucky"] = self.man.list()

        self.punc = "!"

        procs = [mp.Process(target=self.bark, args=(dog_name, words)) for dog_name in self.dogs.keys()]
        for pr in procs:
            pr.start()

        for pr in procs:
            pr.join()

    def bark(self, dog, words):
        for word in words:
            self.dogs[dog] += [word + self.punc]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("multi")
    m_pen = MultiPen(["bark", "woof", "yip"])
    print(m_pen.dogs)

    print("basic")
    b_pen = BasicPen(["bark", "woof", "yip"])
    print(b_pen.dogs)
```

#### Using `multiprocessing.Namespace`

I tried to implement a version with an `OrderedDict` version using `multiprocessing.Namespace()` as shown below:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from collections import OrderedDict

class NamePen(object):
    """ordered dict attempt"""

    def __init__(self, words):
        man = mp.Manager()
        self.ns = man.Namespace()
        self.ns.dogs = OrderedDict()
        self.ns.dogs["Lucky"] = man.list()
        self.ns.dogs["Molson"] = man.list()
        self.ns.dogs["Taco"] = man.list()

        self.punc = "!"

        procs = [mp.Process(target=self.bark, args=(dog_name, words)) for dog_name in self.ns.dogs.keys()]
        for pr in procs:
            pr.start()

        for pr in procs:
            pr.join()

    def bark(self, dog, words):
        for word in words:
            self.ns.dogs[dog] += [word + self.punc]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("ordered")
    n_pen = NamePen(["bark", "woof", "yip"])
    print(n_pen.ns.dogs)
```

When I run this code, the `NamePen` return an empty `OrderedDict`. An alternative I considered was creating a `multiprocessing.Namespace` and just assigning attributes as dictionary keys, but then I couldn't find a way to list the attributes, since running `__dict__` on a `multiprocessing.Namespace` doesn't work. Consequently, I'm starting to doubt in the `multiprocessing.Namespace` approach is correct.

#### Using `multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager`

After reading through [questions about giving multi-process access to object instances](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3671666/1079075), I tried to use the recommended approach of the `BaseManager`:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
from collections import OrderedDict

class MultiPen(object):
    def __init__(self, words):
        man = BaseManager()
        man.register('OrderedDict', OrderedDict)
        man.start()
        self.dogs = man.OrderedDict()
        self.dogs.update(molson=[])
        self.dogs.update(taco=[])
        self.dogs.update(lucky=[])

        self.punc = "!"

        procs = [mp.Process(target=self.bark, args=(dog_name, words)) for dog_name in self.dogs.keys()]
        for pr in procs:
            pr.start()

        for pr in procs:
            pr.join()

    def bark(self, dog, words):
        for word in words:
            self.dogs[dog] += [word + self.punc]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("multi")
    m_pen = MultiPen(["bark", "woof", "yip"])
    print(m_pen.dogs)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "multiproc_class.py", line 43, in <module>
    m_pen = MultiPen(["bark", "woof", "yip"])
  File "multiproc_class.py", line 17, in __init__
    procs = [mp.Process(target=self.bark, args=(dog_name, words)) for dog_name in self.dogs.keys()]
  File "<string>", line 2, in keys
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 732, in _callmethod
    raise convert_to_error(kind, result)
multiprocessing.managers.RemoteError: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Unserializable message: ('#RETURN', odict_keys(['molson', 'taco', 'lucky']))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I think this implies that I'm using the object manager incorrectly.

### What is an acceptable answer

I don't care if I need to use a library or a custom class. However, the OrderedDict does have to be an attribute of the class, as shown in the above examples.

Comment: Can't help you further, but the error is a result of `self.dogs.keys()`. `self.dogs` is a proxy and is trying to return the `odict_keys` view object from the manager server, but it is not picklable.