# multiprocessing.Manager nested shared objects doesn't work with Queue

Tags: python, memory-management, process, multiprocessing, queue

Python docs of the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module state:

> *Changed in version 3.6:* Shared objects are capable of being nested. For example, a shared container object such as a shared list can contain other shared objects which will all be managed and synchronized by the `SyncManager`.

This does work with `list` and `dict`. However, if I try to create a shared `Queue` inside a shared `dict`, I get an error:

```
>>> from multiprocessing import Manager
>>> m = Manager()
>>> d = m.dict()
>>> d['a'] = m.list()
>>> d['b'] = m.dict()
>>> d['c'] = m.Queue()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 772, in _callmethod
    raise convert_to_error(kind, result)
multiprocessing.managers.RemoteError: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 228, in serve_client
    request = recv()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 251, in recv
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(buf.getbuffer())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 881, in RebuildProxy
    return func(token, serializer, incref=incref, **kwds)
TypeError: AutoProxy() got an unexpected keyword argument 'manager_owned'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Seems like https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/39e7307f9aee is the changeset which introduced nested shared objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is caused by `AutoProxy` currently not handling all `BaseProxy` arguments. There's a [pull request](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/4819) which has not been merged yet. You either need to monkey-patch `AutoProxy`, or you look into `multiprocessing.managers.py` and apply the changes in the patch [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/4819/files) directly to your source code.

It's really important to fix both lines in the patch to prevent a memory leak in the server process. The `manager_owned`-flag is used to let the `BaseProxy` code know, when to skip a reference increment for a proxy the manager owns himself (through nesting).

Comment: Is this solution sufficient, or does it risk a memory leak? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46779860/multiprocessing-managers-and-custom-classes

Comment: @DavidParks I had a play with the source code before I wrote this answer and the answer (both) you linked is not sufficient as it currently is. Created objects will always have a reference in the manager-process and hence never be destroyed.

Comment: Thanks, when you say created objects, you mean objects created by the manager? If so, then if we create a fixed number of objects (say a few manager.Queue objects) then it sounds like it's not an issue, right? Or do you mean every object that is added to a manager.Queue, or other manager data structures, will leave a residue?

Comment: @DavidParks Sorry, with "objects" I meant only the nested queues itself, other objects you put inside it should not be affected. So unless you create masses of nested queues, it's not going to be a big issue. But the additional change to make it a clean solution is small enough, so I would just implement the patch as a whole and tick it off forever.

Comment: For what it’s worth, I created a monkey patch that handles this all properly (handling the `manager_owned` flag properly and re-registering the existing SyncManager registrations that use AutoProxy). See [my answer on the duplicate post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63797696/100297).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to patch the underlying python library, you can apply this patch in your own code using the following.

I've copied the change from the [pull request](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/4819) reference by @Darkonaut and made package name modifications so it works outside the original package. This is placed at the module level of any module that uses `multiprocessing.managers`.

Note that the [solution I referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46779860/multiprocessing-managers-and-custom-classes) in comments in @Darkonaut's answer produced seg faults in my own testing, but this solution did not.

```
import multiprocessing.managers

def AutoProxy(token, serializer, manager=None, authkey=None,
              exposed=None, incref=True, manager_owned=False):
    '''
    Return an auto-proxy for `token`
    '''
    _Client = multiprocessing.managers.listener_client[serializer][1]

    if exposed is None:
        conn = _Client(token.address, authkey=authkey)
        try:
            exposed = dispatch(conn, None, 'get_methods', (token,))
        finally:
            conn.close()

    if authkey is None and manager is not None:
        authkey = manager._authkey
    if authkey is None:
        authkey = multiprocessing.process.current_process().authkey

    ProxyType = multiprocessing.managers.MakeProxyType('AutoProxy[%s]' % token.typeid, exposed)
    proxy = ProxyType(token, serializer, manager=manager, authkey=authkey,
                      incref=incref, manager_owned=manager_owned)
    proxy._isauto = True
    return proxy

multiprocessing.managers.AutoProxy = AutoProxy
```

Comment: In W10_64, with Py3.7.7 adding this in the code raise an error when you try to run a `SyncManager`: `_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function AutoProxy at 0x000001DAF1615EE8>: it's not the same object as multiprocessing.managers.AutoProxy`. It seems to work in WSL.

Comment: Patching the function is not enough. [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63797696/100297) to the older post this one is a duplicate of also re-registers all SyncManager types that used the unpatched AutoProxy, because otherwise you get pickling errors.