# Sharing array of objects with Python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, shared-memory, python-3.8

For this question, I refer to the [example in Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html) discussing the "use of the `SharedMemory` class with `NumPy` arrays, accessing the same `numpy.ndarray` from two distinct Python shells".

A major change that I'd like to implement is manipulate array of class objects rather than integer values as I demonstrate below.

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import shared_memory    

# a simplistic class example
class A(): 
    def __init__(self, x): 
        self.x = x

# numpy array of class objects 
a = np.array([A(1), A(2), A(3)])       

# create a shared memory instance
shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=a.nbytes, name='psm_test0')

# numpy array backed by shared memory
b = np.ndarray(a.shape, dtype=a.dtype, buffer=shm.buf)                                    

# copy the original data into shared memory
b[:] = a[:]                                  

print(b)                                            

# array([<__main__.Foo object at 0x7fac56cd1190>,
#       <__main__.Foo object at 0x7fac56cd1970>,
#       <__main__.Foo object at 0x7fac56cd19a0>], dtype=object)
```

Now, in a different shell, we attach to the shared memory space and try to manipulate the contents of the array.

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import shared_memory

# attach to the existing shared space
existing_shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name='psm_test0')

c = np.ndarray((3,), dtype=object, buffer=existing_shm.buf)
```

Even before we are able to manipulate `c`, printing it will result in a segmentation fault. Indeed I can not expect to observe a behaviour that has not been written into the module, so my question is what *can* I do to work with a shared array of objects?

I'm currently pickling the list but protected read/writes add a fair bit of overhead. I've also tried using [`Namespace`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.Namespace), which was quite slow because indexed writes are not allowed. Another idea could be to use share Ctypes Structure in a [`ShareableList`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html#multiprocessing.managers.SharedMemoryManager.ShareableList) but I wouldn't know where to start with that.

In addition there is also a design aspect: it appears that there is an [open bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue39959) in `shared_memory` that may affect my implementation wherein I have several processes working on different elements of the array.

Is there a more scalable way of sharing a large list of objects between several processes so that at any given time all running processes interact with a unique object/element in the list?

**UPDATE:** At this point, I will also accept partial answers that talk about whether this can be achieved with Python at all.

Comment: Of course, one would have to `close` and `unlink` the shared objects at the right time but that was left out because it wasn't completely relevant.

Comment: Off the top of my head I can't come up with an idea, so I'll just ask: what type of work are your processes supposed to do? I assume It's more than a simple map operation...

Comment: @AlexNe In short: yes, this is more complex than map; the example is merely conceptual. If you're interested in more detail: each process can be thought of as an individual "programmable unit", all of which execute asynchronous, fully distributed algorithms to accomplish co-ordination, cohesion etc.

Comment: Are you using a numpy array instead of a list for any specific reason? Numpy arrays can work with shared memory shenanigans because they are implemented in a way that can work directly with memory buffers. This perk is automatically lost as soon as you have objects instead of "numbers" in them. CPython and specifically the GIL tend to misbehave when multiple threads are attacking the same objects. If you want to have shared numerical-array-ish structures, then I use numpy primitives. If you want to share objects, I would tell to think about the specifics/requirements of those objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I did a bit of research ([Shared Memory Objects in Multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10724332/10639694)) and came up with a few ideas:

#### Pass numpy array of bytes

Serialize the objects, then save them as byte strings to a numpy array. Problematic here is that

1. One one needs to pass the data type from the creator of `'psm_test0'` to any consumer of `'psm_test0'`. This could be done with another shared memory though.
2. `pickle` and `unpickle` is essentailly like `deepcopy`, i.e. it actually copies the underlying data.

The code for the 'main' process reads:

```
import pickle
from multiprocessing import shared_memory
import numpy as np


# a simplistic class example
class A():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def pickle(self):
        return pickle.dumps(self)

    @classmethod
    def unpickle(self, bts):
        return pickle.loads(bts)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Test pickling procedure
    a = A(1)
    print(A.unpickle(a.pickle()).x)
    # >>> 1

    # numpy array of byte strings
    a_arr = np.array([A(1).pickle(), A(2).pickle(), A('This is a really long test string which should exceed 42 bytes').pickle()])

    # create a shared memory instance
    shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(
        create=True,
        size=a_arr.nbytes,
        name='psm_test0'
    )

    # numpy array backed by shared memory
    b_arr = np.ndarray(a_arr.shape, dtype=a_arr.dtype, buffer=shm.buf)

    # copy the original data into shared memory
    b_arr[:] = a_arr[:]

    print(b_arr.dtype)
    # 'S105'
```

and for the consumer

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import shared_memory
from test import A

# attach to the existing shared space
existing_shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name='psm_test0')

c = np.ndarray((3,), dtype='S105', buffer=existing_shm.buf)

# Test data transfer
arr = [a.x for a in list(map(A.unpickle, c))]
print(arr)
# [1, 2, ...]
```

I'd say you have a few ways of going forward:

1. Stay with simple data types.
2. Implement something using the C api, but I can't really help you there.
3. Use [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/)
4. Use [Mangers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3697322/10639694). You maybe loose out on some performance (I'd like to see a real benchmark though), but You can get a relatively safe and simple interface for shared objects.
5. Use [Redis](https://redis.io/), which also has Python bindings...

Comment: Although this doesn't resolve my exact problem, this answers the problem posed in the question. The answer also has enough resources linked so that one can work out a solution on their own so I will mark this as accepted. Thanks!