# How to import a class instance in python without reinitializing it?

Tags: python, python-import

I have a class instance that I want to use in multiple files:

```
from .services import ClientService
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
client = ClientService() # <-- this instance

from . import scheduler
```

The class itself:

```
class ClientService(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.processing_demos = False
        self.demos_to_be_processed = []

    . . . .

    def push_demos(self, demo_list):
        self.processing_demos = True
        for demo in demo_list[::-1]:
            self.demos_to_be_processed.append(demo)

    def update(self):
        . . . .
```

I import it in two places, one runs the update method in a while loop and another one is in an apscheduler job that runs every 30 seconds.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value
from . import app, client
import time

def client_update_loop():
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.01)
        client.update() # <-- use here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    proc = Process(target=client_update_loop, args=())
    proc.start()  
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
    proc.join()
```

```
from . import client

. . . .

client.push_demos(request_demos_list) # <-- use here
```

The problem I run into is that the client instance in the first file is different from the one in the second file. I assume it happens because it runs `client = ClientService()` when importing twice which creates two separate objects. I tried checking whether the client object was already created using env variables but it didn't help. I also tried moving the initialization to a different file but it ran into the same problem. At this point I'm out of ideas on how to go around this. I would like some suggestions on how to go around this (perhaps I need to restructure my modules in a different way).

**Edit**:
After reading the comments I understood the actual problem (when I start a new process, it just copies objects as they are which results in two unsynced objects) and decided to put my update loop in asyncio rather than a different process:

```
async def client_update_loop():
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.01)
        client.update()
. . . .
asyncio.run(client_update_loop())
```

That way it runs flask and my update loop in parallel while using the same client instance.

Comment: You are using a *subprocess*, i.e. you are working with *two independent Python prodcesses*, they will not share state.

Comment: This has *nothing* to do with imports, importing never magically re-instantiates an object. An import *intitalizes a module*, or simply accesses an already initialized module from a cache, and then modifies the namespace in a way particular to the exact syntax you used.

Comment: Oh, didn't know this. Thanks for the info, will look into it.

Comment: Relevant question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671666/sharing-a-complex-object-between-processes