# How to share data between two processes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

How can I share values from one process with another?
Apparently I can do that through multithreading but not multiprocessing.
Multithreading is slow for my program.

I cannot show my exact code so I made this simple example.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from threading import Thread
import time

class exp:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 0
            
    def func1(self):

        self.var1 = 5
        print(self.var1)

    def func2(self):

        print(self.var1) 


if __name__ == "__main__":

    #multithreading
    obj1 = exp()
    t1 = Thread(target = obj1.func1)
    t2 = Thread(target = obj1.func2)
    print("multithreading")
    t1.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    t2.start()

    time.sleep(3)


    #multiprocessing
    obj = exp()
    p1 = Process(target = obj.func1)
    p2 = Process(target = obj.func2)

    print("multiprocessing")
    p1.start()
    time.sleep(2)
    p2.start()
```

**Expected output**:

```
multithreading
5
5
multiprocessing
5
5
```

**Actual output**:

```
multithreading
5
5
multiprocessing
5
0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sharing a complex object between processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671666/sharing-a-complex-object-between-processes)

Comment: It depends on the data you want to share. I recommend to use Queues https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**I know there has been a couple of close votes against this question, but the supposed duplicate question's answer does not really explain *why* the OP's program does not work *as is* and the offered solution is *not* what I would propose. Hence:**

Let's analyze what is happening. The creation of `obj = exp()` is done by the main process. The execution of `exp.func1` occurs is a different process/address space and therefore the `obj` object a must be serialized/de-serialized to the address space of that process. In that new address space `self.var1` comes across with the initial value of 0 and is then set to 5, ***but only the copy of the `obj` object that is in the address space of process `p1` is being modified; the copy of that object that exists in the main process has not been modified***. Then when you start process `p2`, another copy of `obj` from the main process is sent to the new process, but still with `self.var1` having a value of 0.

The solution is for `self.var1` to be an instance of `multiprocessing.Value`, which is a special variable that exists in *shared memory* accessible to all procceses. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing%20value#multiprocessing.Value).

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Value

class exp:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = Value('i', 0, lock=False)

    def func1(self):

        self.var1.value = 5
        print(self.var1.value)

    def func2(self):

        print(self.var1.value)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    #multiprocessing
    obj = exp()
    p1 = Process(target = obj.func1)
    p2 = Process(target = obj.func2)

    print("multiprocessing")
    p1.start()
    # No need to sleep, just wait for p1 to complete
    # before starting p2:
    #time.sleep(2)
    p1.join()
    p2.start()
    p2.join()
```

Prints:

```
multiprocessing
5
5
```

**Note**

Using shared memory for this particular problem is much more efficient than using a managed class, which is referenced by the "close" comment.

The assignment of 5 to `self.var1.value` is an *atomic* operation and does not need to be a *serialized* operation. But if:

1. We were performing a non-atomic operation (requires multiple steps) such as `self.var1.value += 1` and:
2. Multiple processes were performing this non-atomic operation in parallel, then:
3. We should create the value with a lock: `self.var1 = Value('i', 0, lock=True)` and:
4. Update the value under control of the lock: `with self.var1.get_lock(): self.var1.value += 1`

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do that: you can use [shared memory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html), [fifo](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-mkfifo-method/) or [message passing](https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/communication.html)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).