# asyncio: pass object trough loops and threads python

Tags: python, python-asyncio

i'm just learning asyncio and threads, so if someting is wrong, sorry

this is my code:

```
async def callback_onlyAlert(update: Update, context):
    await update.message.reply_text('Ok! \nI will send you a message only when you can withdraw your USDN')
    #run alert 
    t = threading.Thread(target=middleware_alert, args=(update, context,))
    t.start()


def middleware_alert(update: Update,context):
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(alert(update, context))
    loop.close()


async def alert(update: Update, context):
     global block
     global withdrawal_block
     while True:
        await  update.message.reply_text("⚠️⚠️ -10 MINUTES! ⚠️⚠️")
        time.sleep(20)
```

when i run it, i get `got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop` error, i know that asyncio make a loop for the main thread, and you can't pass object trough loops, so i think that's why i get this error

anyway i get update and context outside that loop, when app starts, so i can't create it after the loop starts, there is any turnaround? or i'm doing something wrong? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you're trying to do is launch the `alert` coroutine so that it runs at the same time as the rest of your code (without waiting for it to finish), I believe the `asyncio`-ish way to do that would be:

```
async def callback_onlyAlert(update: Update, context):
    await update.message.reply_text('Ok! \nI will send you a message only when you can withdraw your USDN')
    #run alert 
    asyncio.create_task(alert(update, context))
```

You shouldn't be running multiple event loops in different threads for this.
Also, you should use `await asyncio.sleep(10)` instead of `time.sleep(10)`, otherwise the entire event loop gets blocked.

Answer (score 0):

### Passing objects through loops and threads

Both thread and async functions share objects if you use `Lock` properly.

I am not sure about the rest part of your code, but it seems you're trying to have a loop per thread which is not possible. But if you really was trying to have multiple event loops for some reason, you should invoke `asyncio.new_event_loop` in a separate process.

*NOTE*: Using processes, you will lose the object-sharing ability. Sure it allows provide prime type objects such as `str`, `int`, etc. between processes but it makes some difficulties for complex objects. If you are interested in that topic, I suggest you to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671666/sharing-a-complex-object-between-processes).

Comment: as i said i'm a newbie using asyncio, maybe i'm doing something wrong. basically i have 5 different functions, each of them do different stuff and create a new thread to call async def alert while they do stuff, alert function needs update object, that's a pretty complex object, i'm using asyncio 'cause i can't call async function with threads