# When to and when not to use map() with multiprocessing.Pool, in Python? case of big input values

Tags: python, dictionary, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, large-data

Is it efficient to calculate many results in parallel with `multiprocessing.Pool.map()` in a situation where each input value is *large* (say 500 MB), but where input values general contain the same large object?  I am afraid that the way `multiprocessing` works is by sending a pickled version of each input value to each worker process in the pool.  If no optimization is performed, this would mean sending a lot of data for each input value in `map()`.  Is this the case?  I quickly had a look at the `multiprocessing` code but did not find anything obvious.

More generally, what simple parallelization strategy would you recommend so as to do a `map()` on say 10,000 values, each of them being a tuple `(vector, very_large_matrix)`, where the vectors are always different, but where there are say only 5 different very large matrices?

**PS**: the big input matrices actually appear "progressively": 2,000 vectors are first sent along with the *first* matrix, then 2,000 vectors are sent with the second matrix, etc.

Comment: I think that [Python multiprocessing: sharing a large read-only object between processes?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/659865/1132524) might have the answers you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your input. The difference between the question you refer to and this one is that the large matrices are essentially *input values* for map (the question linked to only uses a single, big object).  Furthermore, it does not look like any of the solutions in the top answer is adapted to the case of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the obvious solution is to send a reference to the very_large_matrix instead of a clone of the object itself? If there are only five big matrices, create them in the main process. Then when the `multiprocessing.Pool` is instantiated it will create a number of child processes that clones the parent process' address space. That means that if there are six processes in the pool, there will be (1 + 6) * 5 different matrices in memory simultaneously.

So in the main process create a lookup of all unique matrices:

```
matrix_lookup = {1 : matrix(...), 2 : matrix(...), ...}
```

Then pass the index of each matrix in the `matrix_lookup` along with the vectors to the worker processes:

```
p = Pool(6)
pool.map(func, [(vector, 1), (vector, 2), (vector, 1), ...])
```

Comment: This sounds like a good idea. I have one question though: will the dreaded *copy on write* curse eventually force a copy of each large matrix in each process?  I have read that Python's object reference counts are stored along with the object: incrementing the reference count through referring to an object copies the whole object into the forked process (under most operating systems–Windows is worse, if I understand correctly).

Comment: Yes, the dreaded copy on write will do that. However, having 5*(P+1) matrices in memory (where P is the number of processes in the pool) is significantly less than one matrix for each item in the list passed to map().

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation about copy-on-write.  I'm not sure I understand why "item in the list passed to map()" use "significantly more" memory than having 5*(P+1) matrices in memory. In fact, the memory footprint of the list is essentially the size of the *5 matrices*, which is *less* that the size of 5*(P+1) matrices (the reason is that Python internally uses pointers to the 5 matrices).

Answer (score 1):

I hit a similar issue: parallelizing calculations on a big dataset. As you mentioned `multiprocessing.Pool.map` pickles the arguments. What I did was to implement my own `fork()` wrapper that only pickles the return values back to the parent process, hence avoiding pickling the arguments. And a parallel `map()` on top of the wrapper.

Comment: Did all your processes end up duplicating your big dataset?  If I understand correctly, you had *one* big dataset: the question is about having a few big sets (there are already solutions available for a single big dataset at http://stackoverflow.com/q/659865/1132524–you might even want to add yours).

Comment: PS: Here is a reference to this "copy on write" memory duplication for read-only objects: http://stackoverflow.com/a/660026/42973.

Comment: That's a good point about python reference counts causing copying pages in the `fork`ed child.