# Python seems to delete Process?

Tags: python, variables, multiprocessing

Here is the example I have created. Essentially, I define two processes as global variables (yes, I know that's bad practice but I'm doing it to show the problem). The target of the `killer` process is the `kill_printer` function, which terminates the `printer` process after 5 seconds. Both processes are `global` objects so this should not be a problem.

```
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Process

def kill_printer():
    print('printer' in globals() and 'killer' in globals())
    sleep(5)
    printer.terminate()

def print_hello():
    while True:
        print('hello')
        sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    global printer
    global killer
    printer = Process(target=print_hello)
    killer = Process(target=kill_printer)
    printer.start()
    killer.start()
    print('printer' in globals() and 'killer' in globals())
```

However, as you can see I have printed tests to confirm that `printer` and `killer` are both global variables after their definition and when `printer` is needed in `kill_printer`. This is because when the program is run, this is the result:

```
True
hello
False
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
Process Process-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 254, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\Google Drive\EES\test.py", line 7, in kill_printer
    printer.terminate()
NameError: name 'printer' is not defined
hello
hello
hello
hello
```

One minute both Processes are in `globals`, and suddenly they're not (causing a `NameError`, and `printer` goes right on printing! What's happening here? Is this problem specific to my use of processes or variables themselves in general?

(If anyone's about to reply that `multiprocessing` isn't necessary here, they should know that the given example is a reduced down example of a program that most definitely does)

Comment: Are you on Windows? It looks like `printer` and `killer` are in the original process's globals, but not the `killer` process's globals. That'd happen on Windows, since it doesn't have fork.

Comment: @user2357112 I am indeed on windows. I have access to a computer with Linux, are you saying it would work on that?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Don't use globals, if you want to send information to other threads use a Queue, and pass args to the target

Comment: I'd say, the error message comes from the *killer* process, which does not inherit the global variables *at all* (neither does the printer process, but it also does not try access them). You did expect the globals to be shared? [They are not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215554/globals-variables-and-python-multiprocessing).

Comment: @ChadS. OK, how would I apply that to my example?

Comment: @dhke Ah, I see. That makes perfect sense.

Comment: As a side note: Life probably becomes a lot simpler when you start the printer from a monitor process and kill it from there, because then you've got access to the process object of the forked-off printer directly.

Comment: And the lesson here is: `Use the *threading* module when on the one single non-POSIX-compliant platform, otherwise known as M$ Windows` ;).

Comment: @ChadS. I will quite happily accept an answer building on your comments that provides a solution to my example.