# Can't get attribute 'abc' on <module '__main__' from 'abc_h.py'>

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, parallel-processing

I am defining a function in  python. Program file name itself is **abc_d.py** . I don't understand if i can import the same file inside again.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
import multiprocessing
num_processor=4
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(num_processor)


def abc(data):          
    w=np.dot(data.reshape(25,1),data.reshape(1,25)) 
    return w

data_final=np.array(range(100))
n=100
error=[]
k_list=[50,100,500,1000,2000]
for k in k_list:

    dict_data={}    
    for d_set in range(num_processor):
        dict_data[d_set]=data_final[int(d_set*n/4):int((d_set+1)*n/4)]
        if(d_set==num_processor-1):
            dict_data[d_set]=data_final[int(d_set*n/4):]

    tasks = dict_data
    results_w=[pool.apply_async(abc,dict_data[t]) for t in range(num_processor)]
    w_f=[]
    for result in results_w:
        w_s=result.get()
        w_f.append(w_s.tolist())

    w_f=np.array(w_f)

print (w_f)
```

where tasks is a dictionary with array.

**Error:**

Can anybody explain the error. I am still not much familiar with the python.

```
Process ForkPoolWorker-1:
Process ForkPoolWorker-2:
Process ForkPoolWorker-3:
Process ForkPoolWorker-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/process.py", line 254, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 108, in worker
    task = get()
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 345, in get
    return ForkingPickler.loads(res)
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/process.py", line 254, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'abc' on <module '__main__' from 'abc_d.py'>
```

Comment: did you import abc_d?

Comment: Please show the full error traceback.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you declare the pool prior to declaring the function you are trying to use in parallel it will throw this error. Reverse the order and it will no longer throw this error. Also, there is a bug in your code, you are feeding all of your data_dict to abc, when you want to feed it as a list. So I changed that line too and it returns some results.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
import multiprocessing
num_processor=4


def abc(data):          
    w=np.dot(data.reshape(25,1),data.reshape(1,25)) 
    return w

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(num_processor)


data_final=np.array(range(100))
n=100
error=[]
k_list=[50,100,500,1000,2000]
for k in k_list:

    dict_data={}    
    for d_set in range(num_processor):
        dict_data[d_set]=data_final[int(d_set*n/4):int((d_set+1)*n/4)]
        if(d_set==num_processor-1):
            dict_data[d_set]=data_final[int(d_set*n/4):]

    tasks = dict_data
    results_w=[pool.apply_async(abc, [dict_data[t]]) for t in range(num_processor)]
    w_f=[]
    for result in results_w:
        w_s=result.get()
        w_f.append(w_s.tolist())

    w_f=np.array(w_f)

print (w_f)
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi i got the same problem but i could fix it.
you have to put the definitions out of the script, because windows can't find the function.
Maybe you put your code in an `if __name__ == '__main__':` query and add the function out of them.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
import multiprocessing





def abc(data):          
w=np.dot(data.reshape(25,1),data.reshape(1,25)) 
return w

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_processor=4
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(num_processor)
    data_final=np.array(range(100))
    n=100
    error=[]
    k_list=[50,100,500,1000,2000]
    for k in k_list:

        dict_data={}    
        for d_set in range(num_processor):
            dict_data[d_set]=data_final[int(d_set*n/4):int((d_set+1)*n/4)]
            if(d_set==num_processor-1):
                dict_data[d_set]=data_final[int(d_set*n/4):]

    tasks = dict_data
    results_w=[pool.apply_async(abc,dict_data[t]) for t in range(num_processor)]
    w_f=[]
    for result in results_w:
        w_s=result.get()
        w_f.append(w_s.tolist())

    w_f=np.array(w_f)

    print (w_f)
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue.
Declaring pool after the function solved the issue.
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(num_processor)

Answer (score -4):

a likely answer that I am pursuing myself is that the function will not pickle.. as discovered by this guy:

https://github.com/joblib/joblib/issues/166#issuecomment-55529781

who is the writer of a multi threading handler.

for those who use global variables in there multi threaded function, refer to this question:

[Globals variables and Python multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215554/globals-variables-and-python-multiprocessing)

Answer (score -4):

You can try to pass the Pool as a parameter ! Alex

Comment: Could you please expand your answer? Perhaps include example code.