# How can I share values between multiprocess?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, functools

How can I send a value which in a process to another process? For example I have something like this code piece. I want to print value in xFunc. Can someone explain how can I do it? Thank you.

```
def yFunc():
    value = 5

def xFunc():
    print(value)

def smap(f):
    return f()

def main():
    f_x = functools.partial(xFunc)
    f_y = functools.partial(yFunc)

    with Pool() as pool:
        res = pool.map(smap, [f_x, f_y])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Edit: value is not constant number it is changing continuously.

Edit2: I found a way for my problem. Here the solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58208695/16660763

Comment: I need to use processes because I tested both processes and threads to measure time. Processes are much faster for my script.

Comment: Did you look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38322574/python-multiprocessing-sharing-of-global-values ?

Comment: No, I didn't see it before. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways.
One way would be to use the global keyword. like this:

```
def yFunc():
    global value
    value = 5

def xFunc():
    print(value + 1)

yFunc()
xFunc()
```

Or like this:

```
value = 5

def yFunc():
    global value
    value = value + 1

def xFunc():
    print(value)

yFunc()
xFunc()
```

Another way would be to pass the variable to the function like this:

```
def yFunc():
    value = 5
    return value

def xFunc(x):
    print(x)

xFunc(yFunc())
```

Hope that's what you were asking.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't use these methods with multiprocess.

Comment: There are no globals that are shared between processes — so this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Python has provided some tools to realize it.

Considering [Pipes, Queues](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues), [Value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#shared-ctypes-objects) and [Managers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#managers).

Comment: Yes, I solved by using Managers(). Thank you.

Comment: If you need to share "simple" values such as integers, then you should use a shared memory implementation such as a [Value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#shared-ctypes-objects) rather than a managed type for efficiency.