# Multiprocessing: why is a numpy array shared with the child processes, while a list is copied?

Tags: python, python-2.7, fork, python-multiprocessing, copy-on-write

I used this [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121790/using-multiprocessing-manager-list-instead-of-a-real-list-makes-the-calculation) (see code at the end) to assess whether a global object is shared or copied when the parent process is forked.

Briefly, the script creates a global `data` object, and the child processes iterate over `data`. The script also monitors the memory usage to assess whether the object was copied in the child processes.

Here are the results:

1. `data = np.ones((N,N))`. Operation in the child process:
   `data.sum()`. Result: `data` is **shared** (no copy)
2. `data = list(range(pow(10, 8)))`. Operation in the child process: `sum(data)`. Result: `data` is **copied**.
3. `data = list(range(pow(10, 8)))`. Operation in the child process: `for x in data: pass`. Result: `data` is **copied**.

Result 1) is expected because of copy-on-write. I am a bit puzzled by the results 2) and 3). Why is `data` copied?

---

**Script**

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121790/using-multiprocessing-manager-list-instead-of-a-real-list-makes-the-calculation)

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import logging
import os

logger = mp.log_to_stderr(logging.WARNING)

def free_memory():
    total = 0
    with open('/proc/meminfo', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            if any(line.startswith(field) for field in ('MemFree', 'Buffers', 'Cached')):
                field, amount, unit = line.split()
                amount = int(amount)
                if unit != 'kB':
                    raise ValueError(
                        'Unknown unit {u!r} in /proc/meminfo'.format(u = unit))
                total += amount
    return total

def worker(i):
    x = data.sum()    # Exercise access to data
    logger.warn('Free memory: {m}'.format(m = free_memory()))

def main():
    procs = [mp.Process(target = worker, args = (i, )) for i in range(4)]
    for proc in procs:
        proc.start()
    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()

logger.warn('Initial free: {m}'.format(m = free_memory()))
N = 15000
data = np.ones((N,N))
logger.warn('After allocating data: {m}'.format(m = free_memory()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Detailed results**

Run 1 output

`[WARNING/MainProcess] Initial free: 25.1 GB
[WARNING/MainProcess] After allocating data: 23.3 GB
[WARNING/Process-2] Free memory: 23.3 GB
[WARNING/Process-4] Free memory: 23.3 GB
[WARNING/Process-1] Free memory: 23.3 GB
[WARNING/Process-3] Free memory: 23.3 GB`

Run 2 output

`[WARNING/MainProcess] Initial free: 25.1 GB
[WARNING/MainProcess] After allocating data: 21.9 GB
[WARNING/Process-2] Free memory: 12.6 GB
[WARNING/Process-4] Free memory: 12.7 GB
[WARNING/Process-1] Free memory: 16.3 GB
[WARNING/Process-3] Free memory: 17.1 GB`

Run 3 output

`[WARNING/MainProcess] Initial free: 25.1 GB
[WARNING/MainProcess] After allocating data: 21.9 GB
[WARNING/Process-2] Free memory: 12.6 GB
[WARNING/Process-4] Free memory: 13.1 GB
[WARNING/Process-1] Free memory: 14.6 GB
[WARNING/Process-3] Free memory: 19.3 GB`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're all copy-on-write.  What you're missing is that when you do, e.g.,

```
for x in data:
    pass
```

the reference count on every object contained in `data` is temporarily incremented by 1, one at a time, as `x` is bound to each object in turn.  For `int` objects, the refcount in CPython is part of the basic object layout, so the object gets copied (you *did* mutate it, because the refcount changes).

To make something more analogous to the `numpy.ones` case, try, e.g.,

```
data = [1] * 10**8
```

Then there's only a single unique object referenced many (`10**8`) times by the list, so there's very little to copy (the same object's refcount gets incremented and decremented many times).

Comment: Ok so I cannot iterate or do a simple look-up without triggering copies. Doesn't it make copy-on-write close to useless?

Comment: COW (copy-on-write) is a an OS concept that Python inherits from `fork()` on platforms supporting that function.  COW wasn't designed with Python's multiprocessing (mp) in mind, and Python's mp wasn't designed with COW in mind ;-)  COW is a platform-specific thing that may or may not be helpful, depending on the application.  Note that for many object types in CPython, the refcount is _not_ stored "with the bulk of the object's data".  In any case, COW was originally invented to implement exec-after-fork, where the advantage is that the vast bulk of the parent process data is never referenced.