# flexible-size read-only (append-only) shared memory list of objects/lists - correct way to store?

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, shared-memory, python-multiprocessing

Data: I have two very long lists (up to 500M elements each) which are *extremely* intensive used (read-only, no modification) by my parallel part of program. First is list of string, second is list of list of integer. Length of element (string or list) in both lists may vary from few (most of the cases) up to few hundreds or thousands (rare situation) of letter/integer.
In parallel code (sub-processes) the lists are used as a read-only data. When parallel execution is finished new elements may be add (append to end) to lists by main-process.

Question:  The question is what is the best way to share such data between processes? Below are solutions which are consider (which I aware of). If I miss something please comment.

Possible solutions:

1. Array from [multiprocessing module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html). It was [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721915/shared-memory-objects-in-multiprocessing) that it can be combined with numpy array. This solutions seems to be the most reasonable. But in requires fixed-length elements - this a real problem for me. I dont have enough RAM to set array element size to length of the longest items which may ever appear. Within this approach I think the most effective way is to set element length to some reasonable value (which will be capable to store most of entries) and remaining longest entries store is second array with big enough element length.
2. os.fork of main-process (with lists described in Data section). It is unix-only but this is not a problem for me. It should benefit from copy-on-write. But both strings (elements of 1st list) and list (elements of 2nd list) are object and [probably reference counting will cause that each time data will be copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37980870/multiprocessing-why-is-a-numpy-array-shared-with-the-child-processes-while-a-l/37980995#37980995)
3. redis (o other db which can store data in ram). I really worry about [performans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40203443/benchmarking-retrieval-from-redis-vs-memory-in-python-using-timeit)
4. store as [mmap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html) object. This gives me huge string-like (and file-like) object. Searching (iterating) over it probably will be the most time-consuming part of my program.
5. store in original form in one process and use queue/pipe to communicate with other processes. Previously, when I used multiprocess.pool.imap with small chunksize communication between processes kills performance. Therefore I believe such solution cannot be apply for really high traffic.

So, based on above it seems to me the most reasonable solution is to use Array and numpy (option 1) and try to split each list into few arrays with different element length. Any comments, suggestions? Did I miss something?

Comment: This is a way too broad of a subject to get a correct answer as it **vastly** depends on how you intend to use the data. numpy shared arrays have some serious limitations and more often than not rethinking your process may yield much bigger performance increase than trying to squeeze out every single `tick` between different approaches.

Comment: @zwer:  I think it is not very important what I will do next with data (this too domain-specific, shortly speaking a lot of small and fast operations) what I believe is important I am very intensively read data from both list and iterate over both list. During last few weeks I significantly improved algorithm but I cannot neither divided both lists into disjointed parts and give only one fragment to each process nor further reduce number of reads. I you know any serious limitations of solution #1 please share with me.  :)