# Multiprocessing without return values

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing, multi-index

I am doing an experiment where the result is high dimensional structured. I use a [`MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#hierarchical-indexing-multiindex) to represent the result object and use `multiprocessing` to compute and fill it. The result set is quite large, which can be easily up to millions to billions of entries. If the result is 3D, I can let the function which does the computation return a `df` and then combine them into a panel afterwards.

When the result object is 5D or higher, I found it not straight-forward and memory consuming to return the subset of result from each function performed in a single process. However, it does not work if I let each process write their result directly to the `MultiIndex` global variable (the result) which had been created before the computation. The values of the result `df` are all `NaN` as it is been created.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: What kind of multiprocessing are you using? I would recommend to take a look at dask data frames or if it's not enough at Apache Spark SQL

Comment: I don't know multiindex. Only sharing memory (not objects) allow shared read and write. Subprocess created by Linux fork will copy a globally shared object if the object is modified by the subprocess. This way, a subprocess modifies its local copy of the object, which is not shared with other processes. I guess that is why you see NaN. see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894791/use-numpy-array-in-shared-memory-for-multiprocessing and also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659865/python-multiprocessing-sharing-a-large-read-only-object-between-processes