# What gets re-loaded in new instances of a program using multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I gather that using multiprocessing causes new instances of the program to be initialized. e.g. the following code would cause 7 instances to be initialized:

```
pool = mp.Pool(processes=7) 
pool.apply_async(process, args=(properties,)) for properties in properties_list]
```

My question though is what is actually getting loaded in the new instance? For example, if i have `file_a.py`, which calls a function from `file_b.py`, and the function in `file_b.py` uses multiprocessing, is it just `file_b.py` that gets re-loaded, or `file_a.py` and `file_b.py`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe all of your imports will be imported.

The details vary depending on your start method.

- **fork method** (the default on Unix) - this actually [fork](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fork)s your program.  In this case, all memory and resources of the parent are cloned to the child.  Whatever was loaded in the parent will be loaded in the child.  (And all resources, like file descriptors, will be shared between the two processes.)
- **spawn or forkserver method** (spawn is the default on Windows) - both of these start at least one new instance of your python interpreter, and pickles whatever arguments and other resources are needed for the run method.  As far as I'm aware, all of file_a.py is parsed, including the import of file_b.py.

In both of the latter cases, the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods) says that "no unnecessary resources are inherited", but this isn't referring to loading imported code; it's talking about operating system resources like shared memory access or file descriptors.

Comment: very well explained, I also [found this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659865/python-multiprocessing-sharing-a-large-read-only-object-between-processes) which explains the memory model used between `multiprocessing` processes