# Why isn't my class attribute preserved when using multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, fastapi, event-loop, class-variables

I have the following class in a FastAPI application:

```py
import asyncio
import logging
from multiprocessing import Lock, Process

from .production_status import Job as ProductionStatusJob


class JobScheduler:
    loop = None
    logger = logging.getLogger("job_scheduler")
    process_lock = Lock()
    JOBS = [ProductionStatusJob]

    @classmethod
    def start(cls) -> None:
        cls.logger.info("Starting Up (1/2)")
        Process(target=cls._loop).start()
    
    @classmethod
    def _loop(cls) -> None:
        cls.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        cls.loop.create_task(cls._run())
        cls.logger.info("Startup Complete (2/2)")
        cls.loop.run_forever()
        cls.loop.close()

    @classmethod
    async def _run(cls) -> None:
        while True:
            ...

    @classmethod
    async def stop(cls) -> None:
        cls.logger.info("Shutting Down (1/2)")
        with cls.process_lock:
            cls.loop.stop()                          # <= This Line
            cls.loop.close()
        cls.logger.info("Shutdown Complete (2/2)")
        cls.loop = None
```

On the `startup` and `shutdown` events of the FastAPI application, the `JobScheduler.start()` and `JobScheduler.stop()` methods will be called.

The `start` method works smoothly, but in `stop` I get an error:

```
File "/backend/app/main.py", line 146, in stop_job_scheduler
2023-08-16 11:46:27     await job_scheduler.stop()
2023-08-16 11:46:27   File "/backend/app/jobs/__init__.py", line 59, in stop
2023-08-16 11:46:27     cls.loop.stop()
2023-08-16 11:46:27 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'stop'
```

But `cls.loop` is set during the `_loop` method (which is executed at the end of `start`) - so why does `cls.loop` still have its initial `None` value when the `stop` method is called?

Are there any better approaches to clean up the background processes when the FastAPI application calls `shutdown`?

Comment: You are not setting `cls.loop` in `start()`. You're setting it in `_loop()`. Are you one hundred thousand percent sure that `_loop()` is being called *before* `stop()` is executed?

Comment: I guess the problem is multiprocessing will fork, and create a separate copy of `cls`, and it will set the `loop` attribute for the copy, not for the one you called `.stop` from.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Oops. It was a typing error, I'll fix it right away. Yes, I'm positive that the `_loop()` is called before `stop()` because I can verify that both `cls.logger.info("Startup Complete (2/2)")` and the processes in `_run()` are completed before I stop the application (hence calling the `stop()`)

Comment: @Selcuk but that's stupid. Why would I want to use a Class Variable, unless I want it to stay the same for everytime the class variable is called/used? I guess I'll try to use a `mutliprocess.Manager` object and see how it goes! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Class variables are singletons, but only for the current process. Think of multiprocessing as if you are spinning up a new `python` interpreter every time you fork/spawn (it is smarter than this, but you get the idea). Consider using multithreading since you need to share memory in this case.

Comment: Oops! I didn't see the `Process` part. Selcuk is right, you get a new copy for each process.

Comment: Does [multiprocessing: sharing a large read-only object between processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/659865) answer your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) in Python is funny. It's more powerful than multithreading but also comes with some caveats. The first of those is that you're actually running a different Python interpreter entirely. That means that global variables and the like are going to get a new copy for each process you run.

Depending on your operating system and choice of start method, your processes may be *forked* or *spawned*. A *spawned* process will start anew, as though a new Python program was just spun up. A *forked* process will get all of the current values of variables from the source process, but it'll still copy all of those variables. Future changes to either process will not affect the other, without explicit synchronization using one of the `multiprocessing` helpers.

You can use a [`Manager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Manager) to synchronize data between processes explicitly. This acts sort of like a local server that both processes connect to. For more explicitly pub-sub data, you can also use a [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) to pass information from one process to another.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Silvio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2288659/silvio-mayolo) and [Selcuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2011147/selcuk) the root cause of the issue was found. For anyone who's wondering how I solved this in practice, here it is:

I stored the `Process` *before the forking* and killed it at the `stop`:

```
class JobScheduler:
    manager = None
    loop = None
    logger = _logger
    process_lock = Lock()
    JOBS = [ProductionStatusJob]

    @classmethod
    def start(cls) -> None:
        cls.logger.info("Starting Up (1/2)")
        cls.loop = Process(target=cls._loop)
        cls.loop.start()
    
    @classmethod
    def _loop(cls) -> None:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.create_task(cls._run())
        cls.logger.info("Startup Complete (2/2)")
        loop.run_forever()
        loop.close() # <= is probably never called
...

    @classmethod
    async def stop(cls) -> None:
        cls.logger.info("Shutting Down (1/2)")
        with cls.process_lock:
            cls.loop.kill()
        cls.logger.info("Shutdown Complete (2/2)")
        cls.loop = None
```

Comment: The only word of warning with *forking* behavior is that it's Unix-specific. You can't fork a process on Windows, unfortunately. Other than that, it's *insanely* convenient.